# SQL Server 2008: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, syntax-error, union

I have a problem with a program I inherited. I needed to adjust a query but nog the query doesn't work anymore.

This is the query I got (don't judge me, it isn't my query :) )

```
SELECT     
   SUM(DATEDIFF(day, verz1.BeginDatumAW, verz1.EindDatumAW) + 1) AS AantalDagen,    
   verz1.CodeBedrijf, verz1.CodeAfdeling, verz1.CodeSectie,
   (SELECT TOP (1) RTRIM(OmschrijvingSectie) AS Expr1
    FROM PEBSectie
    WHERE (CodeBusiness = verz1.CodeBusiness) AND (CodeAfdeling = '00')) AS BSNS,
   (SELECT TOP (1) RTRIM(OmschrijvingSectie) AS Expr1
    FROM PEBSectie AS PEBSectie_1
    WHERE (CodeBusiness = verz1.CodeBusiness) AND (CodeAfdeling = verz1.CodeAfdeling) AND (CodeGroep = '00')) AS AFD,
   (SELECT TOP (1) RTRIM(OmschrijvingSectie) AS Expr1
    FROM PEBSectie AS PEBSectie_1
    WHERE (CodeBusiness = verz1.CodeBusiness) AND (CodeAfdeling = verz1.CodeAfdeling) AND (CodeGroep = verz1.CodeGroep) AND (CodeSectie = '00')) AS GRP,
   (SELECT TOP (1) RTRIM(OmschrijvingSectie) AS Expr1
    FROM PEBSectie AS PEBSectie_1
    WHERE (CodeBusiness = verz1.CodeBusiness) AND (CodeAfdeling = verz1.CodeAfdeling) AND (CodeGroep = verz1.CodeGroep) AND (CodeSectie = verz1.CodeSectie)) AS SEC
FROM         
    Verzorging AS verz1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    AangepastWerk AS aw1 ON verz1.VerzorgingId = aw1.VerzorgingId
WHERE     
    (verz1.EindDatumAW <= @EndDate) AND 
    (verz1.BeginDatumAW >= @StartDate) AND 
    (aw1.Verwijderd = 0) AND               <------------ First statement added
    (aw1.NietErkend = 0 OR aw1.NietErkend IS NULL) AND 
    (DATEDIFF(day, verz1.BeginDatumAW, verz1.EindDatumAW) > 0))
GROUP BY 
     verz1.CodeBusiness, verz1.CodeBedrijf, verz1.CodeAfdeling, verz1.CodeGroep, 
     verz1.CodeSectie, verz1.TypeAWOfWO, verz1.TypeOngeval
HAVING      
     (verz1.TypeAWOfWO = 'A') AND (verz1.TypeOngeval = 'AO') OR
     (verz1.TypeAWOfWO = 'Arbeidsongeval') OR
     (verz1.TypeAWOfWO = 'arbeidsongeval')
UNION ALL
SELECT     SUM(DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, verz1.EindDatumAW) + 1) AS AantalDagen, verz1.CodeBedrijf, verz1.CodeAfdeling, verz1.CodeSectie,
                      (SELECT     TOP (1) RTRIM(OmschrijvingSectie) AS Expr1
                        FROM          PEBSectie AS PEBSectie_3
                        WHERE      (CodeBusiness = verz1.CodeBusiness) AND (CodeAfdeling = '00')) AS BSNS,
                      (SELECT     TOP (1) RTRIM(OmschrijvingSectie) AS Expr1
                        FROM          PEBSectie AS PEBSectie_1
                        WHERE      (CodeBusiness = verz1.CodeBusiness) AND (CodeAfdeling = verz1.CodeAfdeling) AND (CodeGroep = '00')) AS AFD,
                      (SELECT     TOP (1) RTRIM(OmschrijvingSectie) AS Expr1
                        FROM          PEBSectie AS PEBSectie_1
                        WHERE      (CodeBusiness = verz1.CodeBusiness) AND (CodeAfdeling = verz1.CodeAfdeling) AND (CodeGroep = verz1.CodeGroep) AND 
                                               (CodeSectie = '00')) AS GRP,
                      (SELECT     TOP (1) RTRIM(OmschrijvingSectie) AS Expr1
                        FROM          PEBSectie AS PEBSectie_1
                        WHERE      (CodeBusiness = verz1.CodeBusiness) AND (CodeAfdeling = verz1.CodeAfdeling) AND (CodeGroep = verz1.CodeGroep) AND 
                                               (CodeSectie = verz1.CodeSectie)) AS SEC
FROM         Verzorging AS verz1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  AangepastWerk AS aw1 ON verz1.VerzorgingId = aw1.VerzorgingId
WHERE     (verz1.EindDatumAW <= @EndDate) 
AND (verz1.EindDatumAW >= @StartDate) 
AND (verz1.BeginDatumAW < @StartDate) 
AND (aw1.Verwijderd = 0)                   <------------ Second statement added
AND (aw1.NietErkend = 0 OR aw1.NietErkend IS NULL) 
AND (DATEDIFF(day, verz1.BeginDatumAW, verz1.EindDatumAW) > 0)
GROUP BY verz1.CodeBusiness, verz1.CodeBedrijf, verz1.CodeAfdeling, verz1.CodeGroep, verz1.CodeSectie, verz1.TypeAWOfWO, verz1.TypeOngeval
HAVING      (verz1.TypeAWOfWO = 'A') AND (verz1.TypeOngeval = 'AO') OR
                  (verz1.TypeAWOfWO = 'Arbeidsongeval') OR
                  (verz1.TypeAWOfWO = 'arbeidsongeval')
```

**Changes:** In both where statements I added the following line:

```
 AND (aw1.Verwijderd = 0)
```

After i added this i keep getting the problems with the following subqueries (for each of the subqueries i get the same error).

```
(SELECT     TOP (1) RTRIM(OmschrijvingSectie) AS Expr1
                        FROM          PEBSectie AS PEBSectie_3
                        WHERE      (CodeBusiness = verz1.CodeBusiness) AND (CodeAfdeling = '00')) AS BSNS,
```

The error I get is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 28
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

I can't seem to figure out what I've done/ what has gone wrong. I hoped a pair of fresh eyes might see something I've missed.

**Note**: The error only occurs after the ***UNION ALL***

I thank you for all your patience

with kind regards

**Edit:** if possible: major Modifications to the query are to be avoided.

Comment: Finally.. Dutch field names. :)

Comment: Where exactly did you add the line `AND (aw1.Verwijderd = 0)`?

Comment: Into the where-statements of both major select statements. Will try to edit my post to make em jump out. @Marc_s thanks for the edit! much more readable now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone,

Thanks for all the time you guys invested into my problem. A fresh pair of eyes (even a pair of non IT-Eyes ;) ) suddenly spotted the problem. There is one bracket too much in the first query (where statement)

```
 (DATEDIFF(day, verz1.BeginDatumAW, verz1.EindDatumAW) > 0))
```

That last bracket shouldn't be there. I was blinded by the errormessage and was looking for the problem in the second query. How the old query still managed to produce valid results (even with an invalid syntax) still baffles me. The query itself will be rewritten to avoid further problems.

Thnx again for all your time

With kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You cannot alias for the select table query..

```
(SELECT TOP (1) RTRIM(OmschrijvingSectie) AS Expr1
 FROM PEBSectie AS PEBSectie_1
 WHERE (CodeBusiness = verz1.CodeBusiness) AND 
       (CodeAfdeling =verz1.CodeAfdeling) AND 
       (CodeGroep = verz1.CodeGroep) AND                                     
       (CodeSectie = verz1.CodeSectie)) **AS SEC**
```

is wrong here for all the table aliasing.

Comment: That's not true. Although the aliases have already been set in the first SELECT (before the UNION ALL), you can also alias the other columns, SQL just doesn't do anything with them. See this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14033